# Verify/Validate JWT token without secret/public key in .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, jwt, asp.net-identity

In .NET Core, I know I could do something like this in Startup.cs (but I don't have Startup.cs in standard .NET framework):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions => {
            jwtOptions.Authority = "my_authority_url";

            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = issuers;
            jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = audiences;

            jwtOptions.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Audience"];
            jwtOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
            };
        });
```

But is there another option in standard .NET Framework?  I have an old project using 4.5.2 I'd like to implement something similar within.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure OAuthBearerAuthentication in your startup. E.g

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        ValidAudience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Audience"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = "my_authority_url",
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    })
});
```

Comment: I don't have Startup.cs in standard .NET framework though.

Comment: Is there any problem in adding one?